# Red blue points on a plane, how to find two closest points of the different color

Tags: algorithm

I have solved the problem when the points are of only same color, and matched the solution with cormen's which is using divide and conquer. here is the algorithm

```
1. divide the plane into two halves.
2. solve the problem recursivley for both halves.
3. for points which could have lesser distance and belong to different halves do the following:
    a. get the minimum distance in points pair call it delta1 and delta 2.
    b. find the minimum of these two call it delta
    c. from the central line build a strip of delta size in both direction and compare,
       now only the points in this strip actually needs to be considered. Since these are the only points which could have less distance than delta.
    d.sort the points across y axis in this strip.
    e. start scanning from the top creating a box of size delta by 2*delta, around every point that occurs.
    f. Now in this size box you can only fit 7 or 8 points, otherwise it would points would become closer than delta, and it would break the constraint.
    g. So there are only a constant number of points to be searched in this box.
    h. number of boxes we have to create depends on number of points. So this whole scanning in the strip would take n*O(1) = O(n) time.
4. So the recursion now is = T(n) = 2*T(n/2) + O(n), solving it gives us O(n lg n) complexity.
```

Now my problem is how to convert it for two color points. any suggestions ??

note: its my bad, I actually need to find the two points of different colors.

Comment: @Daniel: It sounds like a programming problem, which is perfectly on-topic.  It needs a better description though.

Comment: Questions about algorithms are on-topic.  I'm dismissing the moderator flags as helpful, because the question quality could be better, but it's clear enough to understand what the OP is asking.

Comment: Bichromatic closest pair is when you need to find a pair of points with **different** colors. As stated, your problem is just two independent regular, same-color, closest pair problems.

Comment: I would like to add here, that using this method it is not possible to solve the bi-chromatic problem, since the basic premise in the step 3f wont be satisfied, there wont be a constant number of points in that box. This is what I have got after thinking on it for a couple of hours. Correct me if it is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Run your current algorithm twice, once for the blue points and once for the red points.  This will yield two point pairs, red and blue.  Choose the point pair with the lesser distance.

Answer (score 0):

It might work if you set the distance between the same pair to infinity and running the same algorithm . The complexity should not change, correct me if I am wrong